# LightBox plugin not working php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, lightbox

I have following html in which I am using LightBox plugin by Lokesh Dhakar. I am getting images dynamically from database and done all required things to carry out with plugin, but still not working. Only the empty lightbox window appears when page loads.

Here is my code:

```html
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($selectImgResult)) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 thumbnail">
        <span style="color:slateblue;">
            <?php echo $fetch['CreateDate']; ?>
        </span>
        <a href="ProfilePic\<?php echo $fetch['ImageUrl'];?>" data-lightbox="images">
            <img src="ProfilePic\<?php echo $fetch['ImageUrl']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fetch['ImageUrl']; ?>" style="height: 178px;" />
        </a>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Where is javascript code to initialize lightbox

Comment: Not working does not gives any clarity, did you had a look into console for errors?  Paste the Javascript code here.

Comment: @Tushar I did'nt find any javascript code as on the official website of lightbox plugin http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ . Rather I am using data-* attributes inside html